# How to install Dual OS, Ubuntu 16.04 with Window 10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

I am new to Linux and I am trying to install it for Learning purpose so I will be familiar with it.

I am installing Ubuntu 16.04 with my existing Windows 10 in my HP Notebook.

I am following a tutorial and it says to select "**Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager**" in "*Installation Type*" dialog box. [See Here !](http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Select-Ubuntu-16.04-Installation-Type.png)

But in my case, I am not getting this option in "*Installation Type*" dialog box.

below is my screenshot when installing Ubuntu..

[image]

What should I don now ?

I have one more question about Swap partition. I am having Windows 10 in C: drive and I want to install Ubuntu in D: drive and I want to make D: drive as a Swap partition, so it can be use by both OS.

And I am having below error when I install Ubuntu. Please check this image and let me know why this Error is :

[image]

Please help me, thank you !

Comment: You may want to look up what swap is, because it's not what you think. Windows also cannot read the Ubuntu filesystem, so you'll need a third partition formatted as NTFS.

Comment: I have all partition formatted with NTFS. Now what should I do when installing Ubuntu with windows 10. because I can not see the option "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" in "Installation Type" dialog box. As it is shown in a Video Tutorial.

Comment: What video tutorial? You shouldn't be installing Ubuntu on an NTFS partition. Ubuntu is meant to create its own.

Comment: you can see First option in below image url..... in my case I am not getting this option... url is http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Select-Ubuntu-16.04-Installation-Type.png

Comment: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) - follow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Ubuntu install process doesn't detect your Windows installation you can't use the Install `Along Side Windows` option.  You would have to use the `do something else` option.

On the `Do Something Else` option you can choose the drive or partition where you want to install Ubuntu.  For this you would have to manually create or provide the partition where you will be installing Ubuntu.  I would recommend the partition be at least 50 Gigs.  I would also suggest that you have a swap partition 10-15 gigs.

Now choose the `Do Something Else` and specify the partition you created for your Ubuntu installation.  This should be an ext4 type partition.

On the set the partition to `/`.  Formatting it is optional if you already have it formatted in the ext4 type.

Pick the drive you want to specify as the boot drive.  Unless you change something in your bios the computer will boot to the first drive which is /dev/sda.

The install will only touch the partition that you specify for the install.  After the installation is completed it will reboot and give you a menu option to choose which OS to boot to, with the default being your new Ubuntu installation.

**Manually Creating Partitions on your Drive**

You can use gparted on from your Live Ubuntu install USB drive to partition your disk.  You can get to this by choosing the `Try Ubuntu` when you boot to the install USB.  Click on the Launch button and type `gparted` to get to it.

Comment: How can I make Ubuntu to detect my existing Window ?

Comment: @AbhishekTandon By installing it.  If you perform the procedures in the answer, it'll install Grub on your system.  Grub will detect all your installed OSes and include them in the boot menu.

Comment: OK... I try this... Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I can see GParted from USB. But I just want to know "my Disk is already partitioned with Windows 10 using NTFS file system. If I select /dev/sda3 (which is D: drive in windows10 ) for Ubuntu for installing. Will it be usable with Windows 10 or not ? I mean can I use this drive partition with window OS or not ?"

Comment: You can use a partition for any OS.  If you want to use it for Ubuntu format it in `ext4`.  If you want o use it for installing Windows make it a type `NTFS`.  Windows is installed on `NTFS` partitions.  Linux is installed on `ext4` partitions.

Comment: @AbhishekTandon Windows can't see an `ext4` format.  It can only see `ntfs` formats.  Linux can see and use either.  However you should only install Linux on an `ext4` format.  It would loose functionally if you tried to install it on an `ntfs` format.

Comment: I followed all the procedure as you mentioned in answer, but it gives Error about "GRUB installation failed". Why this happened..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44804/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-abhishek-tandon).

Comment: This issue was resolved in the chat session.  I walked the user thought the steps provided in the answer.

Comment: -- Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Since you said HP Notebook R15 , I'm assuming you also have the same BIOS Setup as I have in my HP Notebook. Plug in your bootable USB and press F9 repeatedly when you start-up your laptop. You will be lead to a boot manager and there you will see 
* 'Your pendrive name ( UEFI )
and
* Your pendrive name only without UEFI

Choose withut UEFI and check whether there is "Install Ubuntu along Windows 10" option.

Please let me know if it fix your problem.

Comment: Yes...it is now showing 1st option as "install Ubuntu alongside windows".

Comment: If it's working, please mark thread as solved to help others with same problem, Happy 2 Help

Comment: It is showing option for "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" !  But when I installed Ubuntu completely it is not booting with Ubuntu OS. Even it is not showing options at boot time to select OS. It is booting automatically with windows 10 itself.  So problem is not solved yet.

Comment: Do you remember where you installed your Boot loader?

Comment: dev/sda4/ and I installed Ubuntu in This drive.

Comment: At right below that Boot loader option is there. if you didn't install it , your laptop won't boot to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

use this link for more help regarding recovering your installed ubuntu. Or try again to install. You will probably seee a new option there.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu again from beginning and this time I select /dev/sda/ for boot loader. This solved my problem and Now I can see Select OS option at boot time for both Ubuntu and Windows 10. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: you can Up vote this question so others can get help if they were face same problem when installing dual OS.